# Extract field using JObject.Parse but got this erros: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object

Tags: c#

I have a json and I need to extract a Case_Id from that json.
My code

```
var data = JObject.Parse(myjson);
var s = data["Case_Id"];
```

What I got on locals it is:

data: {{ "Case_Id": "5005t0000", "Done": true, "errors": [] }}

I need to extract Case_id: 5005t0000, but I got the following error:

Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
at ST_7271bd8ea5184e43a42427d8897da929.ScriptMain.Main()

How Can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try your data without the extra {}

```
{ "Case_Id": "5005t0000", "Done": true, "errors": [] }
```

An example that works,

```
string myjson = "{ \"Case_Id\": \"5005t0000\", \"Done\": true, \"errors\": [] }";
var data = JObject.Parse(myjson);
var s = data["Case_Id"];
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: But my I receive myjson with this extra {}.How can I remove these?

Comment: It's not a valid JSON, is this data in your control or from someone else?

Comment: Myjson is "{ \"Case_Id\": \"5005t0000\", \"Done\": true, \"errors\": [] }"; but my data is  {{ "Case_Id": "5005t0000", "Done": true, "errors": [] }}, I do not understand why it add an extra {}

Comment: If you are talking about the debug view for the data object, the {} indicates that the variable is an object type (in your case, data is JObject), and it does not mean it added {} in the json.  However, my program should work as expected. What other code do you have?

Comment: If my code is correct I do not understand why I got an error:

Comment: Can you show all the code? or try my code in your program and see if you have any errors?